# Attribute Error: pipeline object has not attribute transform

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pipeline, apache-spark-ml

I have built a logistic regression model using spark ml pipelines and saved it. I am trying to apply the pipeline on new set of records and receiving an error. My pipeline has vector assembler, standard scaler and logistic regression model in it.

I tried `pipeline.transform` and received the below error

> AttributeError: 'Pipeline' object has no attribute 'transform'

Below is the code

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
pipelineModel = Pipeline.load("/user/userid/lr_pipe")
scored_temp = pipelineModel.transform(combined_data_imputed_final)
```

Here is how I saved my pipeline

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression

vector = VectorAssembler(inputCols=final_features, outputCol="final_features")
scaler = StandardScaler(inputCol="final_features", outputCol="final_scaled_features")
lr = LogisticRegression(labelCol="label", featuresCol="final_scaled_features", maxIter=30)

stages = [vector,scaler,lr]

pipe = Pipeline(stages=stages)

lrModel = pipe.fit(train_transformed_data_1).transform(train_transformed_data_1)
pipe.save("lr_pipe")
```

I am expecting it to complete all the pipeline steps and score the records.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and after I looked up the source code, and I found there is a PipelineModel module that we should load into it. Once I have changed that, it works :D

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline, PipelineModel
pipelineModel = PipelineModel.load("/user/userid/lr_pipe")
scored_temp = pipelineModel.transform(combined_data_imputed_final)
```